# ImageView fitting in limited space and retain the same scale down ratio

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to put 3 ImageView in a ViewGroup vertically and they should look like this in a "Big Screen" device.

However, When this is on a "Small Screen", only the last image scaled down.

I would like all 3 ImageView scale down in the same ratio. See expectation below.

Big Screen:
[image: Big Screen]

Small Screen:
[image: Small Screen]

Expectation on Small Screen:
[image: Expectation on Small Screen]

Code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/red"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/cat" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/cat" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/cat" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to use with scrollview

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using scrollview just add your layout inside scrollview...

And if you don't want to add scroll view you can achieve it using weight...

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/red"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/al_rossais_1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/al_rossais_1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/al_rossais_1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your solution would affect the outcome on big screen device. And yes, scrollView could be a less favoured alternative.

Comment: It didn't affect the outcome on bigger screens

Comment: you can use static height of linear layout

Comment: Aha.  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in LinearLayout should be the fix. I overlooked that. Thanks

Comment: wrap_content didn't work for all the screens

Answer (score 0):

Try using a height of `0dp` for the *ImageViews* with a layout weight of `1` for each as follows:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:src="@drawable/cat" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:src="@drawable/cat" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:src="@drawable/cat" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This will divide up the height of the *LinearLayout* among the views equally while maintaining the aspect ratio. You also will not need the gravity to be specified.